# Tcl 8.4 - Plotting a bar graph

Tags: tcl

I wanted to create a histogram (Look more like a bar chart) of a table with 5 rows and 2 columns, each of the column being an x-axis and y-axis.

I am new to TCL, and before posting here I have tried multiple things! I found that there is a package called plot chart, downloaded form the wiki and tried!

```
#! /bin/env tclsh
lappend auto_path /u/vbhaskar/work/proj2/ECE_x81_PROJECT_2
package require plotchart
canvas .c -background white -width 400 -height 200
pack   .c -fill both
#
# Create the plot with its x- and y-axes
#
set s [::Plotchart::createXYPlot .c {0.0 100.0 10.0} {0.0 100.0 20.0}]
foreach {x y} {0.0 32.0 10.0 50.0 25.0 60.0 78.0 11.0 } {
    $s plot series1 $x $y
}
$s title "Data series"
exit 0
```

Tried the above code, didn't understand completely but better.

I get the error saying package not found.

Is there a simple way of achieving my functionality in Tcl 8.4 version ? I am doing `source <file_name.tcl>` in the Synopsys DC shell

Answer (score 0):

I will not use any library, but some simple code.

```
set mylist [list 0 1 2 8 3 9 4 2 5 19 6 12]
array set arr $mylist

#parray arr

foreach element [array names arr] {
    puts -nonewline "x($element) "
    for {set i 0} {$i <= $arr($element)} {incr i} {
        puts -nonewline "-"
    }
    puts -nonewline "$arr($element)"
    puts "\n"
}
```

Check the o/p:

```
x(4) ---2

x(0) --1

x(5) --------------------19

x(6) -------------12

x(2) ---------8

x(3) ----------9
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Bordoloi! It helped!